# Core Data Values to strings for UILabels

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsstring, nsnumber

I have some values that are stored with core data, and I have opened the application's sqlite database to make sure that the values are being stored correctly, but when I try to display the values they come out all funky.  I store the values from the core data entity in an array then try to call the values.  Basically I am new to developing with objective c and think I need some formatting help.  Here is the code block displaying the funky numbers on output:

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dJournal.dateTime];

cell.dateLabel.text = dateString;
cell.insulinTypeLabel.text = dJournal.insulinType; 
cell.glucoseLevelLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%e",dJournal.glucoseLevel ];
cell.carbTotalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",dJournal.carbTotal ];
cell.insulinAmountLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%E",dJournal.insulinUnits ];

return cell;
```

Here is the core data generated class file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * dateTime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * glucoseLevel; //Double
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * insulinType;  //string - no problem with
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * insulinUnits; //Double
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * carbTotal; //Integer64
```

I also have tried:

```
[[NSNumber numberWithInt:carbTotal] stringValue]
```

no luck.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `%e`, `%d` etc? If you want to print out objective-C objects you need to use the `%@` format specifier, e.g.

```
cell.glucoseLevelLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dJournal.glucoseLevel];
```

If you are displaying numbers however, you should actually be using an instance of `NSNumberFormatter` to generate locale-aware strings.

Comment: Thank you!!  Can you possibly give me a nsnumberformatter line?  I used %e, %E because in an obj c book I have it said to use those for doubles (along with %f,%g,%G).  Thank you Mike.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong specifier. Try to use

```
 [NSString stringWithFormate:@"%@",your_string];
 [NSString stringWithFormate:@"%d",your_integer];
 [NSString stringWithFormate:@"%.02f",your_float];
```

`.02` indicates up to which place after decimal you want